# How to replace an expression containing dash using sed?

Tags: sed, replace

I would like to replace the expression `"Park-144201"` by `"Park144201"` in a long text file. How to perform it using `sed?

Comment: Do you mean you only want to replace the hyphen in the exact string `"Park-...`?

Comment: No, I would like to replace the whole expression.

Comment: `echo 'Park-144201' | sed 's/-//'` something like this?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are 55 of such type of strings, which must be replaced by other expressions.

Comment: No, this string is included in a long text, where it should be replaced.

Comment: There is no way to get a good answer here, with so many "No". You need to provide input file / expected output file and you need to define in which expressions should the hyphen be removed, and most important in which expression hyphen must NOT be removed (and justify why). Scripts/Solution must follow a logic formula, which seems to be absent here.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to apply `sed` to a file to edit just your expression, you could use

```
sed -i 's/Park-144201/Park144201/g' your_file.txt
```

Comment: No, I don't like to remove all dashes, I would like to replace only `"Park-144201"` by `"Park144201"` in a text file. This is only an example. `"Park` and `"144201"` can be arbitrary - but given - texts.